# Query all records that do not contain specific association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models:

```
Questions
-- belongs_to :user
-- has_many :answers
Answers
-- belongs_to :user
-- belongs_to :question
Users
-- has_many :questions
-- has_many :answers
```

How do i query for all questions that the user has not answered?

I tried something like this, but it does not return any questions:

```
Question.includes(:answers).where.not( :answers => { :user_id => current_user.id } )
```

#### Update

Ended up doing something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
    has_many :questions, through: :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :users, through: :answers
end
```

Then I can get the unanswered questions by using:

```
@answered = current_user.questions
@unanswered = Question.all - @answered_questions
```

Comment: Do you have column user_id on answers and questions tables?

Comment: @Catmal yes it is on both tables

Comment: Hmm it should work then..I think you have to look somewhere else the query is correct.. Are you sure that you have records with no answers from current user?

Comment: @Catmal it will work but it will not logical, appropriate & following _OOAD_ in right way. I have corrected design in answer.

Comment: @ray associations were not set in the right way, but that was not really related to the question or the reason query does not return records..

Comment: @catmal I did it a little differently from. I used hmt for both questions and users. I will update code, please let me know what you think

Comment: Yes at some point you should update your code according to @ray answer. But even if you do that I think your problem is not solved..

Comment: @Catmal updated with the solution i used. I did not see ray's answer in time. But I'm not sure if his solution is better?

Comment: @loop you defined `@answered` and not `@answered_questions`. Please verify

Comment: I'm not sure about the syntax you are using, but assuming it's correct I think that it returns questions that do not belong to current user..

Comment: @Catmal Association is not properly defined, so SQL query fired will be proper as per working but will have issue(2) as I defined in my answer. _loop_ please paste SQL query you got.

Comment: @Catmal Solution for `1+1` can also be provided as it is valid question, thing is to maintain standard and provide right way

Answer (score 1):

Your associations must be like,

```
Users
-- has_many :questions
-- has_many :answers, through: :questions
Questions
-- belongs_to :user
-- has_many :answers
Answers
-- belongs_to :question
-- delegate :user, to: :question
```

No need to have foreign_key `user_id` inside `answers` table. Remove it using migration.

*Why do changes as above needed?*

1. Unnecessary storing procedure of foreign_key `user_id` in nested relation.
2. What if we have answers having question and user where that respective question do not belongs to respective user. Follow **OOAD** while relating dependant tables. Read [Rails ActiveRecord Association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: i updated the question. also why wouldn't `answers` need `user_id`? Each answer belongs to a user. Do you mean `questions` do not need `user_id`?

Comment: `answers` table do not need user_id. Please post SQL you got with your query.

Answer (score 0):

Left join saves the world !!!

```
Question.includes('left join answers on answers.question_id = questions.id').
includes('left join users on users.id = answers.user_id').
where( users: { id: nil } )
```

Comment: Error returned: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'left join answers on answers.question_id = question.id' was not found on Question; perhaps you misspelled it?`